# Slide navigation content in an unordered list with overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, css

I have a navigation (ul) with a fixed width and the content exceeds that width. I want to add a forward and back button that scroll the content (li) within the UL - seems simple but this doesn't seem to work. any suggestions? I have thought of removing the ul/li structure and/or placing the links in an absolutely positioned div within a container that has overflow hidden and scrolling the absolutely positioned inner div's left and right coordinates on click but that seems like too much markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {margin:10px; font:10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
ul {width:300px; height:20px; float:left; clear:right; display:block; overflow:hidden; padding:0; margin:0}
ul li {display:block; font:16px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; float:left; clear:right; list-style:none; margin:0 10px 0 0;}
p {height:20px; float:left; display:block;font:16px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0 10px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p><a href="" id="back">&lt;&lt;</a></p>
<ul>
    <li>first link</li>
    <li>second link</li>
    <li>third link</li>
    <li>fourth link</li>
    <li>fifth link</li>
    <li>sixth link</li>
    <li>seventh link</li>
</ul>
<p><a href="" id="forward">&gt;&gt;</a></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#back").hide();
$("#forward").click(function() {
        $("ul").animate({
            'scrollleft': '150px'
        }, 2000);
});
});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/Xdj9Y/2/)

We can:

- get the width of the largest LI element
- set that width to all LI's (and text-align:center)
- create an overflow:hidden DIV container and put inside the slider with set width to show 3 LI elements.
- add a counter - to always know where we are - sliding
- add a buttons check function (to remove unneeded button)
- add a function to do the animations

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // get the width of the wider LI and set to all LI elements
    var max = 0;
    $('#slCont ul li').each(function(){
        var this_width = $(this).outerWidth();
        if (this_width > max) {
            max = this_width;
        }
        $(this).width(max);
    });
    $("#slCont ul li").width(max);
    $('#sl, #slCont').width((max*3)+30); // +30 are all the LI margins of 3 images (CSS 5px)
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
    var galW = $('#slider').width(),
        ulN = $('#slCont ul li').length,
        c = 1;
    $('#slCont').width(galW * ulN);
    function b(){
        cc = (c === 1) ? $('#back').hide() : $('#back').show();
        ccc =(c >= ulN/3) ? $('#forward').hide() : $('#forward').show();    
    }
    b();
    function a(){
        $('#slCont').animate({left: '-'+ galW*(c-1)}, 800);
    }
    $('#forward').click(function() {
        c++; b(); a();
    });
    $('#back').click(function() {
        c--; b(); a();
    });    

});
```

Now you can add as many LI as you want
and even you don't wave to care if one LI's text will be a bit longer.

Comment: roXon - It doesn't seem to work in Chrome - but awesome in FF, seems an issue with #sl starting at 100% width where as in FF its 285px so its something in the math function?

Comment: I'll check now and I'll make you know.

Comment: @Dirty Bird --> REEDITED! (I improved the script to get the width of the largest LI element - and now it WORKS :) ) Let me know if you like this one!

Comment: man thats awesome! thx a lot - I'm gonna go through it line by line and learn from it! I need to learn more about the ternary operators and ++, -- as js operators. kick ass.

Comment: @Dirty... if you want I can comment line-by-line my code to help you understand!

Comment: roXon - that would be great and much appreciated, i want to get away from using plug ins and start actually coding! thx mate.

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design Here you go! : http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/Xdj9Y/3/ Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

It's not complete solution but the main idea is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4uymG/16/

This script stops when boundary reached.

```
$(function(){
    $("#back").hide();
    var menuContainerWidth = parseInt($('#menu-container').outerWidth());
    var menuWidth = parseInt($('ul').outerWidth());

    $("#forward").click(function() {
        $("#back").show();
        var left = $('ul').position().left - 100; 
        if (left <= menuContainerWidth - menuWidth) {
            left = menuContainerWidth - menuWidth;
            $("#forward").hide();
        }
        $("ul").animate({ left: left + 'px' }, 1000);
        return false;
    });

    $("#back").click(function() {
        $("#forward").show();
        var left = $('ul').position().left + 100; 
        if (left >= 0) {
            left = 0;
            $("#back").hide();
        }
        $("ul").animate({ left: left + 'px' }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Version 2.0** http://jsfiddle.net/4uymG/41/

Comment: Hi, check the 2nd version of the solution I was made. It's dynamically defines the  width of the tab and slide one by one on tabs. Problem with previous solution was in styles. In FF and Opera it crops inner slider `div`.